# Html Output tag posted to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

For a project I'm working on I have a calculation run in the background that calculates 2 values I enter. It then takes the result of the numbers and displays it through the output tag in HTML. I was wondering if it is possible to have the output value be submitted and posted with the rest of my form?

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" oninput="    totalamount.value = Math.round(adult.value * 10) + Math.round(student.value * 7); changedue.value = Math.round(moneygiven.value - totalamount.value);">
    <fieldset>
        <select name="showtime" required>
            <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Performance</option>
            <option value='1' type="number" >Show 1 </option>
            <option value='2' type="number" >Show 2 </option>
            <option value='3' type="number" >Show 3 </option>
        </select>
        <h4>Ammount of Adults</h4>
        <input name="adult" id="adult" type="number" required>
        <br />
        <h4>Ammount of Students</h4>
        <input name="student" type="number" required>
        <br />
        <h4>Money Owed</h4>
        <output name="totalamount" for="adult student"></output>
        <br />
        <h4>Money Given</h4>
        <input name="moneygiven" type="number" required>
        <h4>Change due</h4>
        <output name="changedue" for="totalamount moneygiven"></output>
        <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

How Would I do this? Or is there a workaround anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to submit the value as part of the form, it needs to be an `<input>` tag. Consider giving it the `readonly="1"` attribute to make it uneditable:

```html
<input name="example" value="123" readonly="1">
```

As an alternative, you could continue using an `<output>` tag, but also place the value into an `<input type="hidden">`, making it part of the form but invisible to the user.

Either way, make sure that the user cannot perform unintended actions by substituting their own value into the input field, instead of the one calculated by your script.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To do so you will have to store the output in hidden field as the output tag is not a form element
[List of form elements](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp)
 
Or alternatively what you can do is instead of passing calculated value you can calculate it on the page where the form is further processed so in this way only values needed for calculations need to be passed

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to store that value inside HTML  tags.

`<form action = "test.php" method ="post" onsubmit="document.getElementById('xyz').value= myval1; document.getElementById('abc').value= myval2;">
<input type = "hidden" name="xyz" id="xyz" value ="">
<input type = "hidden" name="abc" id="abc" value ="">`

Doing this will make the values of those hidden fields automatically changed as per values in "myval1" and "myval2". You can also calculate these values on the form submit.